# Dynamically insert images into a GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I am making a small game. I want to put images in a Grid View using a dynamic array. To accomplish this, I have declared an array with a random size.

How can I insert images in this dynamic array and show the images in the Grid View?

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
 public int randomNumber=rnd.nextInt(10);
 public int[]mThumbIds=new int[randomNumber];
```

Comment: from where are you taking images and how ???

Answer (score 0):

This is the project in github i use to show a bunch of images from the net

https://github.com/pablorr18/TiFlexiGrid

Answer (score 0):

Hello first of All you dont use a grid view or any other normal view for games because they are all running on UI Thread!!!
Better use SurfaceView wich implements the surfaceholder callback interface!

secondly: i dont know what you want to achieve by that...you want insert bitmaps into arrays? then make an array of bitmaps or an arraylist

nevertheless you should work objectoriented and make objects for your task: if you want some advice please post more information so we can give you a right direction to head into...dont forget my first advice...surfaceview is your friend